# Windows CE Icon lost when using CAB installer

Tags: visual-studio, embedded, windows-ce, icons, ico

I have a C# Windows CE 5.0 application. I am using VS2005. My executable shows the correct icon (32x32 8 bit). If I move the .exe file to the CE device using ActiveSync then the icon is still correctly displayed. When I use a CAB file to install the application the icon is lost. Currently the icon is an embedded resource. Any suggestions. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

With Windows CE you must do a soft reset for the icons to appear. Even when doing a full uninstall and reinstall of the program with the CAB the icons look at the image stored in cache.

Comment: You only have to do a reset if the device has the icon already cached.  FOr example when you deploy it to end-users, they won't have to reset to get the icon.